# Simple IF statement with ActionScript 2.0

Tags: actionscript

Hi and **please do not** judge my poor scripting or advice me to move to AS 3.0 or give me a solution that has absolutely ridiculous amount of scripting.

Just tell me what I'm doing wrong, I'll handle the rest. Thanks.

Basicly, I want to show certain pages depending on the x variable. But this code always ends up in gotoAndStop("2") even if the x variable is greater than -5, so the code doesn't work.

**Here's my code:**

```
if (x <= -5) {

    gotoAndStop("2");

} else if ((x > -5) && (x < 0)) {

    gotoAndStop("3");

} else if (x == 0) {

    gotoAndStop("4");

} else if ((x > 0) && (x < 5)) {

    gotoAndStop("5");

} else if (x >= 5) {

    gotoAndStop("6");

}
```

Comment: It seems ok to me. Try tracing out the value of x at the beginning. Just did a quick test with a loop that goes from -10 to 10.

Comment: My mistake... They should be gotoAndStop(2), not  gotoAndStop("2")... I'm such a fool :P

Comment: haha, it happens to all of us. I missed that detail as well. Glad you figured it out.